# jquery hide/show two divs does not work, perhaps conflict with jqueryui accordion?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, hide, show

I have a page that has two divs of the same dimensions placed exactly one above the other , each of which contains a jqueryui accordion. One div is visible and the other is hidden.  There are also two href's.  The first href should show the first div and hide the second (which is the default state), and the second href should show the second div and hide the first. This way, a user can click on either link and see one accordion or the other.

Here is the relevant html:

```
<html><head>

<link href="jquery/css/vp/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/development-bundle/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

<div id="pagewrapper" >

  <div id="mainteam" >

   <!-- First DIV with an accordion inside -->
   <div id="vpteamcontainer"> 
       <div id="accordion">
         <h3>Section 1</h3>
         <div><p>Section 1 Content</p></div>
         <h3>Section 2</h3>
         <div><p>Section 2 Content</p></div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <!-- Second DIV with another accordion inside -->
   <div id="vpadvisorscontainer"> 
       <div id="accordion2">
         <h3>Section 1-2</h3>
         <div><p>Section 1-2 Content</p></div>
         <h3>Section 2-2</h3>
         <div><p>Section 2-2 Content</p></div>
     </div>
   </div>



<!-- Div containing the two href links to show/hide the above divs -->

    <div id="somediv">
      <ul class = "someULclass">
        <li ><a href="#" id="vpteam" class="somelinkclass">Show First div and Hide Second div</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#" id="vpadvisors" class="somelinkclass">Show Second div and Hide First div</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the relevant CSS for the above DIVS (stripped of width, height, borders, etc) which I am including because perhaps one of the parent divs' css parameters may be affecting the divs I cannot show/hide:

```
#pagewrapper {
    position:relative;
    float:none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
}


#mainteam {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}

#vpteamcontainer {
    display:block;
}

#vpadvisorscontainer {
    display:none;
}
```

So I have javascript that calls the two accordions (#accordion and #accordion2, and that works just fine, followed by javascript that attempts to show and hide the two divs when the links are clicked:  (code edited to try to keep it brief):

```
<!-- START JQUERY accordions -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "fill"
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion2" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "fill"
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- END JQUERY accordions -->

<!-- START JQUERY SHOW HIDE -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#vpteam" ).click(function(){
    $( "#vpteamcontainer" ).show();
    $( "#vpadvisorscontainer" ).hide();
});

$( "#vpadvisors" ).click(function(){
    $( "#vpteamcontainer" ).hide();
    $( "#vpadvisorscontainer" ).show();
});
</script>
<!-- END JQUERY SHOW HIDE -->
```

Note:  I also have javascript to show two modal dialogs that display an html page in an iframe within the dialog box (jqueryui dialog) called from two separate href links.  I have kept that out of here because it does not seem relevant, except that somewhere here I saw an item discussing how rthe fade effect (used in displaying and closing the dialogs), has some issue with show/hide).

RESULTS:
1- The accordions are generated into their corresponding divs and work as expected.
2- The show/hide links do nothing.
3- I have tried using `.css("display, none")` and `.css("display. block")`, as well as `.css("visibility, visible")` and `.css("visibility, hidden")` instead of `show()` and `hide()`, and no matter what I do, I cant get ANY of the options to work.

Perhaps I have also been too explicit or lengthy in my explanation, and if so I apologize.

As I write this, I wonder if the problem is related to the contained accordions or if it  may be related to the href links and how I try to execute the javascripts that show and hide the divs?

Thanks to any and all that give me some suggestion

Comment: share your working code on http://jsfiddle.net and it will be easy for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  Will do so next time. Although new to it, Javascript is awesome.  How could I have gotten by without it?

Answer (score 1):

your code should be like this

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#vpteam" ).click(function(){
       $( "#vpteamcontainer" ).show();
       $( "#vpadvisorscontainer" ).hide();
    });

    $( "#vpadvisors" ).click(function(){
       $( "#vpteamcontainer" ).hide();
       $( "#vpadvisorscontainer" ).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  See my comment to Codeguy007.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working with this javascript code. I used `on.("click")` instead of `click`.

http://jsfiddle.net/JDJpe/1/

```
$(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "fill"
        });
});


$(function() {
        $( "#accordion2" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "fill"
        });
});

$(document).on("click","#vpteam",function(){

    $( "#vpteamcontainer" ).show();
    $( "#vpadvisorscontainer" ).hide();
});

$(document).on("click","#vpadvisors",function(){

    $( "#vpteamcontainer" ).hide();
    $( "#vpadvisorscontainer" ).show();
}));
```

Comment: Thanks Codeguy007.  This works perfectly.  I am new to javascript and realise from your answer and that of Mr kakawat below that I was missing making my javascript a function.  As I understand it, in your case, you changed the click to an event that then executes the show hides as a function.  Mr. kakawat's solution just makes the whole thing a function. I may be understanding it wrong, but in any case, I think both solutions great!  Thanks again to both.

Comment: @Max Esquivel - Thanks can you vote for one of the answers. I would say that Mk. Kakawat's is the more correct answer.